# fetch value from one td to other?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey friends I just want to know how can I use value of a Div in other Div. Since I am working on two Selection Box. Now as I select value from one I want to know that value to my other selection Box, Rest I can work with

This is MY first selection box from which I want to send value to 2nd.

```
<td>
    <select id="asd">
        <option value="a"></option>
        <option value="b"></option>
        <option value="c"></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

this is my second selection box where I want to fetch the value from 1st

```
<td>
    <select id="xyz">
        <option value="a"></option>
        <option value="b"></option>
        <option value="c"></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you need to filter the values in your 2nd selection box based on the selection of the first one ? what exactly do you need to do with the value of 1st box ?

Comment: You need to set value, selected in first `<select>` to second `<select>`? Also, what kind of solution you need? Plain JavaScript or using jQuery?

Comment: Also there are no divs.

Comment: Yes Exactly @Dilantha

Comment: @limelights hey whatever is used whether div or td or selectionbox or anchor.Just my 2nd one wnat to know id or value of first one. Thats all

Comment: @Olegas whatever is mehot no worry. and yes i want to do the same as you said

Comment: if you need something like on this site http://www.all-monitors.com/compares then use xml or ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k9he/) with a working solution.

Here's a sneak peek:

```
var firstSelect = document.getElementById('asd');

firstSelect.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('xyz').value = firstSelect.value;
};
```

---

**Edit:**

It's **very unclear** what you want...

If you can use jQuery, you can get the selected value of the first select easily like this:

```
$('#asd").val();
```

You could use that anywhere in your code (including for loops and in statements).

Comment: Its not that easy I dont want to set value there i want to set class of second selectionBox by using. I just want to retrieve the value but not to print there. your solution will print value while i want to use that value for if condition inside forEach loop @jahroy

Comment: @kushaljain - Please clarify.  I don't understand what you mean.  I don't see any `if statement` or `for loop` in your code at all.  Is there any chance you can use jQuery?  It makes stuff like this _insanely_ easy.

Comment: @kushaljain - Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/7k9he/2/) that changes the style of the 2nd `td` when the first `select` changes.  It uses jQuery, which makes it incredibly easy (as you can see).  I have no clue how to do this withouth jQuery (and have little interest in figuring it out).

Comment: @kushaljain - Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/7k9he/3/) that lets the first select determine how many elements are in the second select.

Answer (score 0):

If use jquery:

```
$('#xyz').change(function(){ 
    var xyz = $('#xyz :selected').val();
    var asd = $('#asd :selected').val();
    console.log(asd+xyz);
});
```